# how to call setImmediate before/above .on('data') fast-csv in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am using fast-csv ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv ) to parse a csv file.

It might have 10k records so it takes a lot of time to parse and almost all other operations on that server get blocked.

So i want to use "setImmediate()" to delay the execution/parsing of records. So that other processess also get cpu time.

```
csv
.fromPath(csvfile, {headers: true, discardUnmappedColumns:true, ignoreEmpty:true})
.validate( function(record) {
    //some validations here
})
.on("data-invalid", function(record){
    logger.error("Validation of record failed:" + record);
})
.on("data", function(record){
    // i know i can add a setImmediate here but i dont want the code to parse all the records in csv at a go.
    // i want to call setImmediate above the .on("data") so that the contacts are validated/parsed slowly(when they get cpu as per setImmediate)
});
```

Either the above or any other way to control/delay the .on("data").

As per my search it cant be controlled since its a stream.

Any and all suggestion welcome !

Comment: A 4MB, 36K record CSV file gets parsed in about 500ms on my machine. How big is your file (file size), and how long does it take to parse? Also, since your code uses a parser stream internally, the file is being parsed asynchronously and should already yield to the event loop.

Comment: actually the parsing is pretty fast but problem is that for every record i have multiple databse operations which slows it down. I cannot optimise on the business logic so i just wanted to delay the operations so that the queue has some space/time to handle other requests.

Comment: Right, so the issue isn't that you need to yield to the event loop, but you want to limit the amount of concurrent database queries? If so, can you share what the code looks like that runs those queries? Are you starting them from inside the `data` handler?

Comment: Nope i have called a setImmediate within the .on("data") handler. Still its clogging. Maybe i should try an use fs to read the csv myself.

Comment: It's to be expected that it's still clogging, `data` is called as fast as possible and it's not asynchronous. That's why calling `setImmediate` won't solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. So what should i try. Basically i want to delay it some how or the other. Update : i am using fs to read the csv and populated an array out of it. So once the array is ready (which will not take much time according to your numbers above) ill process records in a batch of 100s. Looping through the array in batch of 100s. If there is a better alternative do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> So i want to use `setImmediate()` to delay the execution/parsing of records...or any other way to control/delay the `.on("data")`

`setImmediate()` will not be able to help you; even though it will yield to the event loop, your pipeline is already yielding to the event loop because of the CSV file being read.

Instead, you can use a module like [`concurrent-map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrent-map-stream) to limit the number of concurrent database queries being performed, which is likely the real problem that you're running in to.

For example, to limit the number of queries to 100:

```
function queryWorker(record, done) {
  performQuery(record, done);
};

var queue       = require('concurrent-map-stream');
var queueStream = queue(queryWorker, 100).on('data', function(record) {
  ...
}).on('close', function() {
  // done
});

csv.fromPath(...).pipe(queueStream);
```

Comment: what happens after 100 ? will it skip the rest ?

Comment: No, it should limit the amount of concurrent queries to 100, but it should still process _all_ records. Be aware that `performQuery` should "return" the data that you want to receive in the `data` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I solved thisproblem by pushing each record(which i get into .on("data")) in an array and then inside .on("end") using async.mapLimit() which solves my problem

Ref here https://github.com/caolan/async#mapcoll-iteratee-callback and found an example here http://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/16-map-limit.html